# Receiving Wrong POST variable

Tags: php, forms, session, mysqli

I'm struggling with a strange issue, here. I have a database where information about sended invitations to an event and the answer to that requests are stored s.th. like:

```
event_id | event | attendee | invited | response
   1         1        1        yes       no
   2         1        2        yes       yes
   3         2        1        no        no
```

Next, I display the results via mysqli and php in a table with radio buttons for simple editing the information. BUT if I send the form it often (not always) happens, that the wrong POST variables are getting handed over, so the database gets messed up, by updating the wrong information.
persons, who where invited an even accepted the invitation, are then shown as uninvited or as declined.

Can anybody tell me, what the issue might be?

```
//creates an empty array for the results of the database

sec_session_start();

$i = 0;
$_SESSION['i'] = array();
$_SESSION['email'] = array();
$_SESSION['ida'] = array();
$_SESSION['pid'] = array();

//db infortmaiton gets stored in the session
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
 $_SESSION['i'][] = $i;
 $_SESSION['email'][] = $row["email"];
 $_SESSION['pid'][] = $row["idperson"];
 $_SESSION['ida'][] = $row["anmeldungsid"];

//radiobuttons with db info get displayed
<td>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="<? echo 'eingeladen'.$i?>" id="<? echo 'einja'.$i?>" value="Ja" <?php echo ($row["eingeladen"]=='Ja')?'checked':'' ?> onclick="showinvite('<? echo 'einja'.$i?>','<? echo 'link'.$i?>')"/>Ja</label><br/>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="<? echo 'eingeladen'.$i?>" id="<? echo 'einnein'.$i?>" value="Nein" <?php echo ($row["eingeladen"]=='Nein')?'checked':'' ?> onclick="showinvite('<? echo 'einja'.$i?>','<? echo 'link'.$i?>')"/>Nein</label>
</td>
//i gets counted up
<? $i++; ?> }
```

After sending the form, a script is opened with a foreach loop going through the session to update the database

```
session_start();

foreach ($_SESSION['i'] as $i) {
    $ida =  $id[$i];
    $idp = $pid[$i];
    $email = $emaila[$i];
    $eingeladen = $_POST['eingeladen'.$i];
    $zusage = $_POST['zugesagt'.$i];

    if ($update_stmt->bind_param("sssii", $eingeladen, $zusage, $bewilligt, $ida, $idp))
    {
    // Update des Teilnahmestatus
    $update_stmt->execute();
    echo "<p style = 'color:green'>neuer Status: ".$bewilligt." - ".$eingeladen." - ".$zusage."</p><br/>";
    $inhaltn .= "neuer Status: ".$bewilligt." - ".$eingeladen." - ".$zusage."\n\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p style = 'color:red'>Vorbereitung des Update Befehls klappt nicht! TeilgenommenID: ".$idteilgenommen."</p><br/>";
     }
}
```

As I said, it seems to work, but not constantly....

Comment: Could you show the rest of the code where you update the info in the DB? From what you have shown of your "receptionning script", you are looping throught the $_SESSION array and you overwrite all your variables in a loop., which is not normal unless you haven't shown all the code.

Comment: @ThomasG I added the updt_stmt to the question...I'm looping through the session to get all the variables (if they differ from the original DB row) updated in the DB

Comment: Could there be a problem with the Storage of the Session? Is there a way to make sure everytime I open the side, the Storage gets filled with correct data?

Comment: Atm we should eliminate possibilities... I see that after the `->execute()` you have a `echo` of your recuperated session variables. What this tells you? Is the data correct at this point, or wrong ?

Comment: @ThomasG, there's the problem. These variables don't match the changes one was making before. For example: I was trying to update one person, but the session had stored and changes much more persons and their information randomly...